# How to prompt a user for run-as credentials when double-clicking an icon?

Tags: windows, runas

I am running a kiosk type system where the user has almost zero permissions.

I want to place an icon on their desktop that would run a specific program as their Active Directory credentials. I am familiar with SysInternals ShellRunAs, but it would require a right-click which means retraining users.

Could I accomplish this by having them double-click on the icon that they normally would and they would get a prompt for username/password and then execute the program as that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If PowerShell is an option for you, a PowerShell script can prompt for credentials and then use those credentials to start a process.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\notepad.exe" -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

The user sees this prompt, and then the process is started.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I think I will give this a shot.

Comment: I had to use full paths: Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ISE.exe" -Credential (Get-Credential) -WorkingDirectory "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0" and it also opened it in new window, which is a little extra.

Comment: You’re starting a new instance of the ISE.  Of course it’s going to open a new window.

Comment: Only downside is this Credential Request dialog does not support logon via biometric devices such as the laptop fingerprint reader.

Answer (score 5):

You can modify the shortcut to [use the command-line `RunAs` utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490813.aspx). For example, here's the target of a shortcut that will try to open a specific folder in explorer as the user *BillyBob*:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:BillyBob "Explorer.exe F:\Projects"
```

The /user argument can also accept domain credentials (either hard-coded, or using the %USERDOMAIN% environment variable:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:%USERDOMAIN%\BillyBob "Explorer.exe F:\Projects"\BillyBob "Explorer.exe F:\Projects"
```

The username can be an assigned to the `%username%` environment variable:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:%username% "Explorer.exe F:\Projects"
```

Or, with both the domain and username coming from the environment:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:%USERDOMAIN%\%username% "Explorer.exe F:\Projects"
```

Once the shortcut is opened, a `cmd.exe` window will show asking for the password of the specified account:[image: Password Prompt]

If you need the user to enter a username, then things get a little hackish and you have to put this in a .bat file:

```
@Echo Off

set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=Username: %=%
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:%INPUT% "Explorer.exe F:\Projects"
```

Comment: The problem is that many different users will need to run the icon, so I can't hardcode "/user:BillyBob"

Comment: You can also use the `%username%` environment variable in the target. i.e. `/user:%username%`

Comment: @Ray B I've edited my answer to demonstrate domain logins and variable usernames.

Comment: Still wouldn't work, it has to prompt for the username as well. The logged in user will always be the kiosk user, not the operator.

Comment: @Ray B I added getting user input at the bottom. At this point, though, it's just cleaner to use PowerShell like Patrick S. suggested. I offer it in case someone wants to have this kind of thing without installing PowerShell.

Comment: I'm actually glad you posted this. It would be handy where PowerShell is not an option (not installed, admins not comfortable with it, execution policy too restrictive, etc.)  I'll be tucking this away in my bag of goodies.

Answer (score 4):

[ShellRunAs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc300361) doesn't strictly require a right-click; it can be (and in fact *is*) called as an ordinary tool with the original program given in the command-line – just like the built-in `runas` but graphical.

```
shellrunas notepad foo.txt
```

This could be used in a shortcut.

Answer (score -1):

This is my way to do it:

```
@echo off
rem @--------Window config
COLOR F3
mode con cols=60 lines=10
echo.%date%
rem @--------Authentication
@echo.
@set /p user=Username:
@echo.
@runas /user:%user% "C:\Programas\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE http://www.google.com"

rem @ if you are in a domain use:
rem @runas /user:DOMAIN\%user% "C:\Programas\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE http://www.google.com"

rem @---------Window close time (after "-n" put window close time in seconds)
ping -n 3 127.0.0.1>NUL

@cls
@exit
```

You can test it and it will work fine.