# Set a shortcut to prompt with "Run as different user" dialog in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, shortcuts, runas

In Windows 7, you can hold down the <kbd>shift</kbd> key, right-click on a shortcut, and select "Run as different user", which will present this dialog:

[image]

Is it possible to create a shortcut in Windows 7 that will always prompt with this dialog without having to take the above-mentioned steps?

Please note: I am aware of [the Runas command](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true) to which many resources refer (e.g. [this](https://superuser.com/questions/124445/run-as-a-different-user-on-a-shortcut), [this](http://www.rickygao.com/how-to-automatically-run-an-application-as-another-user/), and [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/dfa11529-528d-4eb5-a8c7-d2b7fad4058b/how-to-setup-shortcut-to-always-run-as-different-user?forum=w7itproui)); my question is about the dialog.

Comment: AutoHotKey may be worth looking at

Comment: Would the [ShellRunAs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc300361) utility (as referenced in this [answer](http://superuser.com/a/379161/470588)) work for you?  You still have to configure the shortcut to call out to `ShellRunAs`, but it will present a UI to prompt the user for their credentials (unlike vanilla `runas`).